# Pad Block Corrupted

Tags: android, vb.net, aes

I have to do the following operation:

1. Encryption VB -> Decryption VB
2. Encryption Android - Decryption Android
3. Encryption VB -> Decryption Android
4. Encryption Android -> decryption VB

So far I succedded do encrypt and decrypt on Android.
When I encrypt in VB and try to decrypt on Android, I get the following exception:

E/Exception: pad block corrupted

I also have to mention that when i encrypt short strings in VB and decrypt them also in VB, everything works well. But when i encrypt a larger array of bytes, the decryption works but the result is not the one expected.

Can somebody give me a hint of how to solve the problem?
Thank you !

Here is my code:

.NET functions

```
Public Function AES_Encrypt2(ByVal byteArray() As Byte, ByVal key As String, Optional ByVal ShortKey As Boolean = False) As String
    Try

        Dim FirstKeyBytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)

        If Not FirstKeyBytes Is Nothing Then
            If FirstKeyBytes.Length < 32 Then
                Array.Resize(FirstKeyBytes, 32)
            End If
        End If

        Dim KeyBytes() As Byte
        If ShortKey Then
            KeyBytes = New Byte(15) {}
            Array.Copy(FirstKeyBytes, KeyBytes, 16)

        Else
            KeyBytes = New Byte(31) {}
            Array.Copy(FirstKeyBytes, KeyBytes, 32)

        End If

        Dim InitialVectorBytes() As Byte = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 'Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")
        Dim SymmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

        SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        SymmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)
        Dim MemStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim CryptoStream As New CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        CryptoStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
        MemStream.Close()
        CryptoStream.Close()

        Dim CipherTextBytes As Byte() = MemStream.ToArray()
        Dim encryptedString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes)

        Return encryptedString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function



Public Function AES_Decrypt2(ByVal encryptedString As String, ByVal key As String, Optional ByVal ShortKey As Boolean = False) As String
    Try

        Dim PlainTextBytes1 As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)
        Dim FirstKeyBytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)

        If Not FirstKeyBytes Is Nothing Then
            If FirstKeyBytes.Length < 32 Then
                Array.Resize(FirstKeyBytes, 32)
            End If
        End If

        Dim KeyBytes() As Byte
        If ShortKey Then
            KeyBytes = New Byte(15) {}
            Array.Copy(FirstKeyBytes, KeyBytes, 16)

        Else
            KeyBytes = New Byte(31) {}
            Array.Copy(FirstKeyBytes, KeyBytes, 32)

        End If


        Dim SymmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()
        Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 'Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")

        SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        SymmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)
        Dim MemStream1 As New MemoryStream(PlainTextBytes1)
        Dim CryptoStream As New CryptoStream(MemStream1, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        Dim pltxt As Byte() = New Byte(PlainTextBytes1.Length - 1) {}
        Dim d As Integer = CryptoStream.Read(pltxt, 0, pltxt.Length)

        MemStream1.Close()
        CryptoStream.Close()

        Dim textConverter As New ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim round As String = textConverter.GetString(pltxt, 0, d)

        Return round

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

And Android methods:

```
public static String encrypt(byte[] input, String key) {
    try {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        String newKey = "";
        if (key.length() >= 32) {
            newKey = key.substring(0, 32);
        } else {
            for (int i = key.length(); i < 32; i++) {
                key += "0";
            }
            newKey = key.substring(0, 32);
        }

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(newKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        //skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(newKey.getBytes(), 0, newKey.length(),  "AES");
        Cipher fileCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        fileCipher.init(1, skeySpec, paramSpec);

        byte[] decrypted = fileCipher.doFinal(input);

        byte[] base64enc = Base64.encode(decrypted, 0);

        return new String(base64enc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(String input, String key) {
    try {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        byte[] base64enc = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), 0);

        String newKey = "";
        if (key.length() >= 32) {
            newKey = key.substring(0, 32);
        } else {
            for (int i = key.length(); i < 32; i++) {
                key += "0";
            }
            newKey = key.substring(0, 32);;
        }

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(newKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher fileCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        fileCipher.init(2, skeySpec, paramSpec);

        int x = base64enc.length;

        return fileCipher.doFinal(base64enc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main issue is that the key generation is different in both pieces of code. Passwords are not keys, you should use either binary, randomly generated keys or a good key derivation mechanism like PBKDF2.

Trying to find a well vetted lib. that does use the same protocol for encryption in .NET and Java (/Android) would also be a good idea.

In general, input to cryptographic algorithms need to be binary. Always compare all inputs of your algorithms using hexadecimal encoding right before executing the algorithm.